# How can i add Events to hard coded forms in c#?

Tags: c#

I've tried to create a form that will create buttons based on the number of items in database

my *int count* is equal to the number of count in my database

I'd like to add events or functions to the created label, that when i click the label it will display in the MesssageBox the name of the label
below is my code,

```
int Count;
        List<Panel> pnl = new List<Panel>();
        List<Label> tasklevel = new List<Label>();
        List<Label> taskStatus = new List<Label>();
        List<Label> taskname = new List<Label>();
        List<PictureBox> image = new List<PictureBox>();


for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            Panel pan = new Panel();
            pan.Name = "panel" + i;
            pan.BackColor = Color.White;
            pan.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            pan.Padding = new Padding(10, 0, 10, 10);
            pan.Height = 80;
            pnl.Add(pan);

            Label lbl = new Label()
            {
                Name = "lbl" + i,
                ForeColor = Color.Black,
                //Dock = DockStyle.Left,
                AutoSize = false,
                Width = 0,
                BackColor = Color.Silver,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
                Padding = new Padding(10, 10, 10, 10),
                Text = "Designing",
            }; tasklevel.Add(lbl);

            Label lblname = new Label()
            {
                Name = "lblname" + i,
                ForeColor = Color.Black,
                Dock = DockStyle.Left,
                AutoSize = false,
                Width = 0,
                BackColor = Color.Gray,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
                Padding = new Padding(10, 10, 10, 10),
                Text = "Designing",
            }; taskStatus.Add(lblname);

            Label tskname = new Label()
            {
                Name = "tskName" + i,
                ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(31, 31, 31),
                Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 11, FontStyle.Regular),
                Dock = DockStyle.Left,
                AutoSize = false,
                Width = 200,
                BackColor = Color.Gainsboro,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                Padding = new Padding(10, 10, 10, 10),
                Text = "Task Name",
            }; taskname.Add(tskname);

            PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox()
            {
                Name = "picBox" + i,
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                AutoSize = false,
                Image = DreametryMIS.Properties.Resources.f1,
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
                BackColor = Color.FromArgb(240,240,240),
                Padding = new Padding(10, 10, 10, 10),
            }; image.Add(picBox);

            pan.Controls.Add(picBox);
            pan.Controls.Add(lblname);
            pan.Controls.Add(lbl);
            pan.Controls.Add(tskname);
            FlowPanel.Controls.Add(pan);
        }
```

I'm new at c#, I hope some can help me

Comment: `Control.EventName += Delegate_Method();` For Example: `textBox1.TextChanged += this.textBox1_TextChanged;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement an event handler like this:

```
public void label_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = sender as Label;
    if (label == null) return;
    MessageBox.Show("Name: " + label.Name + " Text: " + label.Text);
}
```

You can now add this handler to the `Click` event of your labels, for example:

```
lblname.Click += label_Clicked;
tskname.Click += label_Clicked;
```

When one of the labels is clicked now, the method `label_Clicked` gets called with the label as argument for `sender`. So by casting the `sender` to `Label` you can easily access the clicked label's properties.

*Note* that you cannot add the handler inside the label's object initializer as you did with the other properties, but need to do it in an extra statement like I showed.

Comment: Now that was easy, thank you so much, tis was a great help

Answer (score 1):

You can too:

```
lblname.Click += delegate { nameOfUrFunction (lblname) };

private void nameOfUrFunction (Label lbl)</code>
{

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TableCell cel2 = new TableCell();
Label lbl2 = new Label();
lbl2.Text = s;
cel2.Controls.Add(lbl2);
tr.Cells.Add(cel2);
TableCell cel3 = new TableCell();
DropDownList ddlcountry = new DropDownList();
ddlcountry.ID = s;
cel3.Controls.Add(ddlcountry);
tr.Cells.Add(cel3);
table.Rows.Add(tr);
form1.Controls.Add(table);
DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)form1.FindControl("CountryId");
DropDownList ddlstate = (DropDownList)form1.FindControl("StateId");
ddl1.AutoPostBack = true;
ddl1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged);
protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```